# Vue render button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My question is about render a button on vue instance, to click in a button and then it render another button with event click, If I simple mount the button it dont get the function tes.

```
const Hello = {
  props: ['text'],
  template: '<button v-on:click="tes"> </button> ',
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Click me'
  },
  methods:{
        alertar: function(event){
                      const HelloCtor = Vue.extend(Hello);
            var instance = new HelloCtor({
                    propsData: {
                  text: 'HI :)'
                }
            })

                instance.$mount() // pass nothing
           this.appendChild(instance.$el)
      },
      tes: function(){
            alert('Teste');
      }
  }
})
```

Erro :

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.js:597
(index):52 Uncaught TypeError: this.appendChild is not a function
    at Vue.alertar ((index):52)
    at invoker (vue.js:2029)
    at HTMLParagraphElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expanding @Philip answer
Basically you can't access parent methods in programatically created components.
You need to specify the methods inside the child components.

```
const Hello = {
  props: ['text'],
  template: '<button v-on:click="this.tes"> Vue Generated</button> ',
        methods: {
    tes: function(){
      alert('Teste');
    }}
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted(){
    this.alertar()
  },
  methods:{
        alertar: function(event){
          const HelloCtor = Vue.extend(Hello);
            var instance = new HelloCtor({
              propsData: {
                  text: 'HI :)'

                }
            })

            instance.$mount() // pass nothing
          this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
      },
      tes: function(){
            alert('Teste');
      }
  }  
})
```

Check this fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/370645/

However in some cases you may be able to access the parent components methods using
[$parent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-parent) directive which I believe will not work when components is created programatically.

Comment: And how I acess the parent ????,  this.$parent.tes2(); and  this.$parent.app.tes2(); does not work :/

Comment: const Hello = {
  props: ['text'],
  template: '<button v-on:click="this.tes"> Vue Generated</button> ',
   methods: {
    tes: function(){
      this.$parent.tes2();
    }}
};

Comment: @Ranieri you *never* want to access a parent's method, it's a bad practice. Components only ever access their own methods and communicate with their childs via prop-bindings and with their parents via events.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create a child component inside of your parent `Vue` that contains the template with the binding to the `tes` function. That means that the child will look in its own methods for `tes`, however it is a property of your parent, not of the child itself so it will never be able to find it in its own scope. You have to add the function to the child component instead:

```
const Hello = {
  props: ['text'],
  template: '<button v-on:click="tes"> </button> ',
  methods: {
    tes: function(){
      alert('Teste');
    }
  }
};
```